# Can a sigma field ever be same as an event space?

Tags: sigma-algebra

---

Suppose, The sample space of the gender of the upcoming baby is:

$S=\{boy,girl\}$

then, $\sigma -field=\{ \{boy\}, \{girl\}, \{boy,girl\}, \emptyset\ \}$

Can the event of having the baby as twins or not having a baby is the same as the sigma field?